# what is editText's data type in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, clipboard, charsequence

I'm trying to copy some text from an editText field in android studio but the app always crashes when I do.
copying works fine, what crashes the app is copying from editText.

I assumed it is String and tried casting it to a CharSequence, still crashes. I also tried copying from a TextView with no success, could it be the casting?

```
button3.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
                        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                        ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("aaa",(CharSequence)editText);
                        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                    }
                }
        );
```

stack trace:

```
2019-04-28 03:46:47.121 29744-29744/my.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: my.app, PID: 29744
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
        at my.app.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:68)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

btw `MainActivity.java:68` is `ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("aaa",(CharSequence)editText);`

Comment: String text = editText.getText();

Set the above line on button click listener.

Comment: `(CharSequence)editText` – That's not how to get the text from an `EditText`. You need to call `getText()` on the `EditText` (as Prafulla Nayak mentions), and optionally `toString()` on that, if you want plaintext. If it's also crashing when you do that correctly, we'll need to see that stack trace, too.

Answer (score -1):

you don't have to use `ClipboardManager` or `ClipData` to copy from your `EditText` or `TextView` all you have to do is add this attribute to your `TextView` or `EditText` to do the work

```
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

**edit**

```
button3.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
                        String text = editText.getText();
                        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                        ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("aaa",text);
                        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                    }
                }
        );
```

Comment: but I do want to save it to clipboard

Comment: when you select the text and press copy it goes directly to your clipboard

Comment: please check my edit

Comment: Please consider my answer , i gave you the correct answer in my edit